# Making a function definition where the right hand side is evaluated before the definition is saved

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, assignment

My question is about assigning the resulting expression after evaluation of a function.

So what I want:

```
FOCf[x, y] := D[f[x, y], x]
```

such it immediately evaluates the right hand side, making it a conditional expression.

How I do it now.

I first shift-enter: `D[f[x, y], x]`. Then, I manually copy the resulting output to the right end of `FOCf[x, y] :=`.

Is there a better way to do this? I already tried using `Evaluate`, but that did not seem to work.

Comment: Is `f` defined prior to defining `FOCf`?

Comment: Not sure how to interpret your question. You can evaluate in place with [Ctrl] + [Shift] + [Enter], or you can use `=` (without the colon) to first evaluate the r.h.s. and then assign the result to the l.h.s. symbol. Btw., normally you indicate variables with an underscore on the left side, e.g. `FOCf[x_, y_]`.

Comment: Yes,f[x_, y_] :=  "conditional expression" before. I can also plot that one, so that seems fine.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the = .

Comment: or you can write `FOCf[x, y] := Evaluate @ D[f[x, y], x]`

Comment: @DickOosthuizen Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that you take a look on this [topic about basic pitfalls in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users).

Comment: Why is this off-topic?   Nothing in the the "basic pitfalls" is relevant, and the solution here helped me (`=` fails when parameter patterns are involved) - although /nothing here explains at all why `Evaluate` gets treated differently than `D` with respect to order of evaluation/!